# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data'" when unpickling object

Tags: python, pickle

I'm trying to unpickle a certain object I saved on another computer. The code

```
with path.open('rb') as f:
    obj = pickle.load(f)
```

is giving me an error:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'data'
```

I have the `data` module on my new computer but the directory structure of the project is different, so while the module was imported as `import data` while computing and pickling the object, it's now imported as `import project.data`. I've tried using

```
import project.data as data
```

at the start of my code but I am still getting the same error. How do I unpickle this object, ideally without having to fully restructure my project again?

Comment: If you've changed the code between saving and loading the pickle file, it might just not be compatible. You might need to modify the code back, load it, dump it to something less picky, like a JSON structure, then redo the changes you want to do and convert the JSON structure back to a pickle file that matches your current code base. In general, pickling is not great for long-term saving of data, I've seen old pickle files become unreadable in too many different situations.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind and find a different saving method in the future.